# How to create dynamic matrix table

Tags: c#

I have some dynamic data like below:

Colors: [Red, Blue, Green]

Sizes: [S, M, L]

Types: [Men, Women]

Now how can I create dynamic matrix table like this:

[I can't post images so please see this link: http://79.175.176.69/table.png](http://79.175.176.69/table.png)

Comment: Would be better if you could elaborate the question more. Anyway this may help you little bit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @f.nasim suggested the `type` you could use for holding such data. If you are asking for a logic to generate these combinations, you first need to show your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might give you the result you are looking for.

```
    var colors = new [] { "Red","Green","Blue" };
    var sizes = new[] { "S", "M", "L" };
    var gender = new[] { "Female", "Male"};

    var matrix = from c in colors
                 from s in sizes
                 from g in gender
                 select new { color = c, size = s, gender = g };
```

Comment: Hello Again.. 
I have a new problem... my arrays and values are dynamic... so How can I generate from x in xxxx dynamicly?